# Programmatically create result row in views

Tags: views

I have created a bunch of content types. Since I am using Drupal only for displaying results fetched from another service I was wondering if there is a way to display results in a view without actually having objects in the database?

For example, I get data from a certain endpoint and I want to display them in a table view. Is there a way to achieve that or would another approach be recommended?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No. Views is only capable of returning Content entities.

The approach I recommend is to use [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import your data into custom entities. You can either [define your own custom content entity](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/creating-a-custom-content-entity), or use [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) to define a custom content entity via UI.

In our organization, we use this basic Feeds -> ECK -> Views approach all the time and it has the benefit of not requiring our support staff to know any PHP. You might also find the [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) module to be useful if you need to retrieve data at a frequency shorter than one hour.